# Bootstrap 3 tooltip event delegation attaching to individual elements

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, events, tooltip, legacy

I am optimizing out frontend with heavy technical debt (jQuery, Bootstrap 3... I know, not up to me) and now comes the turn of tooltips. This page in particular has several hundred elements using tooltips which are initialized the usual way:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

This of course targets individual elements resulting in hundreds of listeners being attached and contributing negatively to performance.

I am using a mix of the `selector` option to attach tooltips to a single common parent and [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46045688/3120489) to be able to initialize tooltips to that same parent multiple times (i.e. tooltips being initialized in different parts of the code with different options):

```
/**
 * Attaches a tooltip to the given jQuery element using event delegation. This technique allows attaching
 * multiple tooltips to the same element with different selectors.
 * @param {jQuery} $el - The jQuery element to attach the tooltip listeners to.
 * @param {Object} options - Bootstrap tooltip options.
 * @returns {jQuery} The jQuery object for chaining.
 */
function attachTooltip($el, options = {}) {
    const defaultOptions = {
        title: function () {
            return $(this).attr('title') || $(this).data('title') || '';
        }
    };
    return new $.fn.tooltip.Constructor($el, {...defaultOptions, ...options});
}
```

I thought this would be good enough (until being able to modernize our code, of couse) but upon inspecting targeted elements with the browser tools, I found out the related event listeners (focusin, focusout, mouseout, mouseover) are still being attached to each individual element matching the `selector`.

```
attachTooltip($('body'), {
    selector: '.ttooltip'
});
```

I would have expected 4 listeners attached to `body` and Bootstrap to handle the selector matching internally, instead of falling back to individual even listeners.

Any insights? Did I get it wrong, or this is by design? Do up-to-date Bootstrap versions handle it as I would expect? Can I hack in the expected behavior somehow, maybe even wrapping a different tooltip library that does behave this way?